# jQuery Checkbox and

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table that is already populated with results. I also have a checkbox I want to use to manipulate table contents.

Checkbox:

Branch

---

- A
- B
- C

my table looks like this

- Name|age|Branch
- adam,12,  A
- Geo, 20, B

I want to be able to remove and add a row in the table based on what is checked. I'm new to jQuery so far all I have is: Any help ?

```
function sortByBranch() {
j$('#sfiltersb li label input[type="checkbox"]').bind("change", function(){
        if(j$(this).hasAttr("checked"){
            //do something
        }
      });

}
```

HTML

```
 <ul id="haystack" class="slist">
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-aa" value="AA" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch AA</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-ab" value="AB" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch AB</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-ac" value="AC" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch AC</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-ba" value="BA" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch BA</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-bb" value="BB" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch BB</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-bc" value="BC" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch BC</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-ca" value="CA" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch CA</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-cb" value="CB" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch CB</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-cc" value="CC" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch CC</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-da" value="DA" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch DA</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-db" value="DB" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch DB</label></li>
                      <li><label class="checkbox" style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="checkbox" name="branch-dc" value="DC" checked="checked" class="scritb" />Branch DC</label></li>
                  </ul>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" id="branch-search-btn" style="width:100%; font-size:13px; min-height:30px;">Search</button>
```

Comment: Please show also the HTML of that part and what you want the checkbox to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.checked` in your if statement to see if the checkbox is checked or not:

```
j$('#sfiltersb li label input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        //add row (sample row)
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td>New row</td></tr>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="A" />
<input type="checkbox" value="B" />
<input type="checkbox" value="C" />
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Branch</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Adam</td><td>12</td><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Geo</td><td>20</td><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Peter</td><td>42</td><td>C</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') === true) {
            var myAlpha = $(this).val();
            $('table tbody tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td></td><td>' + myAlpha + </td></tr>'); // add a row with the value of the checkbox in the last col
        } else {
            $('table tbody tr td:contains(myAlpha)').closest('tr').remove(); // remove the row that has the value of the checkbox in the last col
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr id="1"><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr id="2"><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="item1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="item2" />
```

This code will remove the row based on the id of the row and the value of the checkbox:

```
$('.check').bind("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#table tr#'+$(this).val().substring(4)).remove();
    }
});
```

This `$(this).val().substring(4)` is going to get the value of the checkbox without the "item" in front.
If your checkbox has value `item78` is going to remove the row with id 78.

**Here a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZSGv/)**